# Unable to publish to Kylin

Tags: smart-contract, permissions, testnet

I have been developing against a local node, for which I created a key-pair.  Now that it's time to publish to the testnet, I've imported said private key into Scatter and linked it to the account to which I'll be publishing.  when I try it:

```
$ cleos -u https://kylin.eos.dfuse.io/ set contract MYACCT . token.wasm token.abi -p MYACCT@active
```

where MYACCT is a placeholder for the real account, I get the error:

> Failed to get existing code hash, continue without duplicate check...
>   Reading WASM from /Users/ekkis/dev/token.wasm... Publishing
>   contract... Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do
>   not satisfy declared authorizations Ensure that you have the related
>   private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked. Error
>   Details: transaction declares authority
>   '{"actor":"MYACCT","permission":"active"}', but does not have
>   signatures for it.

I presume that though `-u` is being passed to cleos, the wallet held by my local keosd daemon is the one being used.  Is that so?

If so:

```
$ cleos wallet keys
```

properly shows the the public key for the key-pair I created, and:

```
$ cleos get accounts $PK
```

shows me the account I'm publishing against in the list returned, and:

```
$ cleos get account MYACCT
```

shows me the expected key bound to both permissions "owner" and "active", though:

```
$ cleos -u https://kylin.eos.dfuse.io get account MYACCT
```

fails with:

> error 2019-06-22T18:41:52.927 thread-0  main.cpp:3899
>   main                 ] Failed with error: unspecified (0) unknown key
>   (boost::tuples::tuple): (0 MYACCT)

and if the above queries are invalid because they refer to the account created on the local node and not the one on the testnet, I can verify that the account is linked to the key pair as I can click on the key in Scatter and under the Linked Accounts page I see the desired account under the EOS Kylin Testnet with the word "active" in what seems like a button

I've tried this with --print-request and --print-response but am no wiser for the output

what is my problem and what does it take to publish a contract on a testnet and where can I find an authoritative guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok.  my problem had to do with the fact that the account I presumed existed on Kylin did not.  the account creation must have failed and, apparently, Scatter allows linking a key to non-existent accounts.  really not good, but it's being fixed in the next release

so I kept looking at Scatter thinking the account was there until someone suggested I check an explorer

so all good now